# How can I setup error reporting with Laminas for a development environment?

Tags: php, exception, zend-framework2, laminas

This may be a simple question but, how do I get some error message with Laminas? I'm trying to migrate an old application from ZF2 to Laminas 3. It's always difficult to get any details from the exceptions thrown. Here's the common "No Exception available" message.

An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
No Exception available

Here's my current view manager config. It has some custom twig templates.

```
return array(
    ...
    'view_manager' => array(
            'display_not_found_reason' => true,
            'display_exceptions'       => true,
            'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
            'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
            'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
            'template_map'             => array(
                    'layout/layout' => getcwd() . '/Module/App/view/layout/layout.twig',
                    'error/404'     => getcwd() . '/Module/App/view/error/404.phtml',
                    'error/index'   => getcwd() . '/Module/App/view/error/index.phtml',
            ),
            'template_path_stack' => array(
                    getcwd() . '/Module/App/view',
            ),
    ),
    ...
```

I've also increased the error_reporting to E_ALL and displayed startup errors. I'd like to get some detailed error messages and maybe a stack trace, but can't see how to set this up within Laminas.

Comment: I would take a look at the `php.log` and go from there. Maybe, during development, add a try/catch to `index.php` around `Application::init($appConfig)->run();`. In this case it might not be your typical `Exception` or `Throwable` and therefore not caught within Laminas.

Comment: Can you show us the content of the `error/index` template? As you said the templates are twig templates. Twig is not the standard templating system for laminas. So the content of your error template could be important.